# Keyframe Animation - Instant Change

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've started to learn about keyframe animation in CSS3. One think I've noticed is that, no matter how I ""time" things with keyframe animations, the transitions are always smooth.

For example; a background color change from 50% to 100%, is a smooth transition as the animation plays from 50% to 100%.

What I'm trying to achieve is a way of doing the animation with an "instant" type of value change..

Again, an example would be:
If 50% value of BG is red and 100% value of BG is blue; the animation should stay red till it reaches to 100% and instantly changes to blue when it is 100% completed.

I'm not sure if my terminology is right or wrong, but some direction would be perfect in any case.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [steps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/timing-function#step-end) as your timing-function to pause the animation until the next keyframe

CSS:

```
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
    -ms-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
    -o-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
    animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
```

Sample code:

```
@keyframes quick {
    0% {
        background-color:green;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
        -o-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
        animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
        background-color:blue;
    }
    100% {
        background-color:red;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes quick {
    0% {
        background-color:green;
    }
    50% {
        -o-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
        background-color:blue;
    }
    100% {
        background-color:red;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes quick {
    0% {
        background-color:green;
    }
    50% {
        -moz-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
        background-color:blue;
    }
    100% {
        background-color:red;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes quick {
    0% {
        background-color:green;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
        background-color:red;
    }
    100% {
        background-color:blue;
    }
}
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    animation:quick 3s;
    -moz-animation:quick 3s;
    -webkit-animation:quick 3s;
    -o-animation:quick 3s;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sC5fy/1/

Comment: Yes! "steps" exactly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

I just had this problem and got round it by marking the initial value at the start and then again right before I wanted the change to instantly happen - see below

```
@-webkit-keyframes image2 {
  0%   {opacity: 1;}
  24.99%   {opacity: 1;}
  25%  {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a kind of similar situation and changing the `timing-function` worked for me:

```css
.animated-item {
    animation: my-animation 1s;
    animation-timing-function: step-end;
}
```

The timing function describes how the animation will progress over one cycle of its duration. You can read more about it in this [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function).

Answer (score -1):

A very simple solution could be adding `background-color: red` to your element, and then, in the `@keyframes` section:

```
%0 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Try it: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbcgh/1/)

Comment: you mean in your own attempt or in the jsFiddle?

Comment: Ah, srry about confusion. Your jsFiddle I mean.

Comment: @Zettam: I see the same. Your jsFiddle is broken.

Comment: Guess it's a browser compatibility issue then. Sorry for that. Works fine in FF18.